# Jersey-Json dependency : error on ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper.java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

I am deploying Jersey in Spring-MVC and trying to produce json output format. I have this annotation `@Produces("application/json")` in MyResource.java. First, I got an error:

> SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class edu.ucdavis.iet.APerson, and Java type class
>   edu.ucdavis.iet.APerson, and MIME media type application/json was not found

I added jersey-json dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The error is gone, but it marks another error on:
src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/ajax/json/ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper.java. The errors are :

> The type org.codeHaus.jackson. 
>   Versioned cannot be resolved. It is 
>   indirectly referenced from required 
>   .class file
>
> The hierarchy of the type
>   ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper.java.
>   is inconsistent.

I have searched many docs and tried to modify the configure files, but none is working.  Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have annotated edu.ucdavis.iet.APerson with JAXBXmlElement or JAXBXmlRootElement.
If yes, you could try to use 'text/xml' instead of 'application/json' to see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work to use 'text/xml', but it works for 'text/plain'. Do you have the samples for JAXBXmlElement or JAXBXmlRootElement? Thanks.

Comment: 'text/plain' type don't rely on jaxb serialization.  This is a sample for jaxb annotation: http://tinyurl.com/4shjd3o
. There are other jersey documents on http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Main

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jackon Json Mapper to your dependencies. ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper probably extends ObjectMapper which is a class in the Jackson jar.

Comment: Could you give me the samples or the links for the codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. I added following contents to pom.xlm. The JSON works fine using CURL on the command-line.

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.4</version>
 </dependency>
```